# Oracle text contains and markup have different behaviour

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-text

I have an Issue with Oracle text.
I search like that:

```
WHERE
    ( contains(description_en, '%to_search.%', 1) > 0 );
```

Now Oracle returns me a row, where there is "to_search" but without the dot.
I suspect that is because Oracle does handle that as wordbreak (Note: The Stoplist is empty).

But if I try to highlight the found result with a `ctx_doc.markup` call:

```
ctx_doc.markup(
      index_name => 'i_fil_lis_ce_fil_des_en',
      textkey => '12238',
      text_query => '%to_search.%',
      starttag => '<result>',
      endtag => '</result>',
      plaintext => true)
```

It does not highlight `to_search` unless I remove the dot in the `text_key`.
This behaviour is the same for other symbols like `? / , / @`. This makes no sense to me, shouldn't oracle treat both occurences of the dot the same?

I understand, that Oracle breaks the word at a dot and other symbols. So that if I search `test` it also finds `test.`. But why the other way around? why should I find `test` if I search for `test.`? and can I turn this off?

Version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit

Answer (score 0):

Check lexer config. I guess that dot is simply ignored by lexer. And Text "vocabulary" does not contain any word "test."

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Oracle Text docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqspcl.htm#CCREF0400)

Please note the non-alphabetic characters like . ? / etc are treated as whitespace (so "to_search." is treated as 'to_search '). To match only to_search. you must declare **"."** as a **printjoin**. (If you do, however, to_search. will not match 'to_search . ') For more on **printjoins**, see [BASIC_LEXER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cdatadic.htm#i1007615)

Comment: Thanks that's an Idea I also had, but printjoins do not work if it is also [defined as punctuation and on the end of a word](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/text.102/b14218/cdatadic.htm) (see punctuations). So I would have to remove `.` as punctuation, define it as printjoin and destroy a lot of intended behaviour, just because oracle also threats the dot as white-space if searched for a dot? What would be useful is a way to only treat symbol as white-space on the indexed text, not on the searched text.....